# "No command 'ionic' found" and "workon: command not found"

Tags: android, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I have a weird problem in my Ubuntu 14.04.
I was developing a mobile application using Ionic with an API using Django-Rest-Framework. After developing, I downloaded jdk and Android SDK so that I can build the mobile app into APK. I also downloaded the android dependencies or tools needed for building. After I downloaded it all, I go to my mobile app folder and type `ionic platform add android` to build it. But the terminal response with "No command 'ionic' found". Even typing `ionic serve` responses the same. I also tried to activate the virtual environment of the API using `workon mobile` but it responses with `workon: command not found`. Does anybody have an idea what might be wrong? Thanks

Comment: please check the result of this command on terminal ionic -v

Comment: Yes, it turns out I have to change the permissions of my /usr/local/ folder. Because that is why I cant access ionic and virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

First Check ionic is install or not by using following command

```
ionic -v
```

It shows version if it nothing to show then install ionic by using following command

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

else update ionic by the following command on your terminal

```
sudo npm update -g
```

And also if you have not got the result then create symbolic link by using following command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

First install using this two line..

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
ioniv -v && cordova -v
```

and then use this line

```
$ ionic start myapp [template]
$ cd MyIonic2Project/
$ ionic serve
```